# Bands of tif file with the same name when exporting with rioxarray

Tags: python, tiff, python-xarray, rasterio

I have an array that looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'ws' (step: 40, latitude: 56, longitude: 145)>
dask.array<pow, shape=(40, 56, 145), dtype=float32, chunksize=(24, 24, 24), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
    time               datetime64[ns] 2023-07-12
  * step               (step) timedelta64[ns] 0 days 06:00:00 ... 10 days 00:...
    heightAboveGround  float64 10.0
    valid_time         (step) datetime64[ns] dask.array<chunksize=(24,), meta=np.ndarray>
  * latitude           (latitude) float64 25.6 25.2 24.8 24.4 ... 4.4 4.0 3.6
  * longitude          (longitude) float64 -158.0 -157.6 ... -100.8 -100.4
    spatial_ref        int32 0
```

When I export with rioxarray to a tif file it saves correctly one band for each `step` but it calls them all in the same way with the band name `ws`. So if I have 40 values in `step` it will create 40 bands all called `ws` in the tif file.

This is my code that export the xarray to a tif file:

```
xarr_ws.rio.to_raster(f'{storm_name[1:]}_ens{ensemble}_wind_speed_by_timestep.tif', tiled=True, windowed=True,)
```

Is there a way to name the band with the value od the `step`?